# how to create controller for directive in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i have created menu directive like this in app.js.

```
.directive('menuShow', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'shared/menu.html',
        }
    });
```

Directive is used in index page as:

```
<menu-show ></menu-show>
```

Now, i want to write functionality code which will be used in menu.html directive.

how to write controller for menu.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a controller for your directive and set this in directive,

```
 .directive('menuShow', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'EA',
            templateUrl: 'shared/menu.html',
            controller: menuCtrl,
            controllerAs: 'test',
            bindToController: true
        }
    });
```